# How to ignore a whole Google sheet line if a case has no content?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, average, google-sheets-formula

like the title says,

I would like to ignore a whole line on google sheet if a cell in that line doesn't have any content, how can I do it?

For exemple I got : [image: sheet]

and I am doing an average stats of those, and some people don't have numbers like you see in that screenshot in some cells there isn't anything, I would like to ignore the whole line and not count it at all, how can I do it?

Thanks for people willing to help me

**EDIT:** I've seen that you can use `=ARRAYFORMULA(isblank(cell:cell))` but it recreates each cell and replaces it by FALSE or TRUE, I would like it to check if one cell is blank, it only creates one cell with FALSE or TRUE

Comment: How are you doing the average stats? With AVERAGE?

Comment: I'm doing it like this `=round(sumif('Form Responses 1'!$AA:$AA,Overview!G$12,'Form Responses 1'!$S:$S)/countif('Form Responses 1'!$AA:$AA,Overview!G$12),1)`

This is for one column

Comment: Sounds like you should use [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534?hl=en).

Comment: I think the screenshot you posted is incomplete - you mentioned "like you see in that screenshot in some cells there isn't anything" but your image only shows one row (row 6). Could you please update it?

Comment: When I said this, I meant that you can see that in those rows there are some cells that are blank, if during my calculation I get a blank cell, I would like it to ignore the whole line, for exemple here the whole line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(C1:C, B1:B<>""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: How are you getting 7.5 tho ? I don't quite understand the formula

**EDIT :** I see, but does it do like for exemple does it ignore the lines B2/C2 B3/C3 B6/C6 ?

Comment: yes it does. 7.5 is average of values: 5, 10 and 15